# In LaTeX how can I find the distance from the label of the y axis of my figure to the border? (it should follow the basis rules))

Tags: plot

I want to follow a rule of thesis that observe the least distance; for example 2.5 cm from the left border, and now because I use the subfloat command and have 4 figures near each other, I want to move the figure  a little to both sides, but I want to know how can I understand how much is the distance of the label of my y axis to the left border or about right also the same?
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! I am afraid that this question is in its current form not really answerable. Please post a minimal working example, i.e. a short compilable document that allows others to understand what you are doing. At this point it is not even clear if you produce the plots with LaTeX, or include them as graphics.

Comment: One can obtain such information using commands like \pgfgetlastxy, or \pgfextractx together with \pgfpointanchor and \pgfpointdiff.  Odds are it will equat [inner sep] which defaults to 0.333em.